# How to resize my application screen size?

Tags: javascript

I have made an application and it opens too large window.
I am running visual studio 2015 and making a JavaScript application.

All the script is in main.js

How do I size it down to match the machine in the application?

1080px x 356px

[Application Opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I9t1.jpg)
I need the application width and height to match the machine. The command has to be done with javascript or jQuery.

Comment: I reported your question. It seems like you are new here but you must definitely read the rules and provide more context, some code, explain which technologies you are using, what you have already attempted etc etc.

Your question it unclear and incomplete and it's hard for anyone to help you out. We are developers don't be shy of using technical terms and provide some code (try to provide the minimum amount of needed code)

Comment: Can not provide code that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS relative `width` property value as shown below:

```
html, body{box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;}
*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing: inherit;}
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: The CSS did only resize the background of the screen but did not resize the window that the program is running. - I even tried jQuery .resize() without success....

Comment: You can apply the same technique to other elements as well. If you have any other question please post them separately. Regards,